# Printing array of objects still gives the same values after changing values of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I'm creating an ADT class using static arrays and another class called "Patient" containing peoples personal information. The problem is if I create a Patient object and insert it inside the array and then change the value of that object, printing the array gives the old objects values even though printing the object itself gives the changed values.

I added an operator= function copying the values but it didn't help me.

List.h

```
class List {
private:
  static const int MAX_ELEMENTS = 5;                       
  Patient elements[MAX_ELEMENTS];    
  int elementCount;                                     
public:
  List();
  int  getElementCount() const;
  bool insert(const Patient& newElement);
  void print(); 
};
```

Patient.h

```
class Patient {
private:
string name;
string home_address;
string phone_number;
string email_address;
public:
Patient();
Patient(string aName, string anAddress, string Aphone, string anEmail);
Patient(const Patient& obj);
// + all the getters and setters for the private values
friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const Patient & p);
Patient& operator=(const Patient& p);
};
```

instert function

```
bool List::insert(const Patient& newElement)
{
 bool flag = true;
 for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++)
  {
    if (elements[i] == newElement)
    {
        flag = false;
        break;
    }
}
if (flag == true && elementCount <= capacity)
{
    elements[elementCount] = newElement;
    elementCount++;
}
else
 flag = false;
 return flag;
}
```

operator= function

```
Patient & Patient::operator=(const Patient & person)
{
   name = person.name;
   home_address = person.home_address;
   phone_number = person.phone_number;
   email_address = person.email_address;
   return *this;
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot share the .cpp files.

This is when an array with only 1 object is printed.

```
Patient: To be entered, To be entered, To be entered, To be entered
```

Giving a name and email address and printing the object using its own overloaded operator<< function and this is the desired output for when printing the array.

```
Patient: bob, To be entered, To be entered, bob@mail.com
```

Actual output.

```
Patient: To be entered, To be entered, To be entered, To be entered
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "put it inside the array"?

Comment: Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @melpomene inserting it to the array

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek Arrays have a fixed number of elements. There is no "insert" operation. Show your code.

Comment: *Unfortunately, I cannot share the .cpp files.* Odds are very high that we don't want to see them anyway. MCVE and all that. We want to see the reduced code sample you used to isolate the bug and reduce the signal-to-noise ratio while debugging. You did try to isolate the bug didn't you?

Comment: @user463035818 how can I make the array print the object with the new changed values. Right now it's printing "To be entered" even though I changed the name and email address.

Comment: @melpomene that is correct. I am basically assigning it to the existing item in the array.

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek So you're asking why `int x = 0, y; y = x; x = 42;` doesn't set `y` to `42`?

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek You are assigning them to an existing item whose previous value you inserted into an array.

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek Might be unrelated to the question. But why are you implementing `List`? `std::vector` doesn't solve your purpose?

Comment: @KunalPuri yes it does,  but I am only allowed to use static array

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek Then why don't you go for `std::array`?

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek Also, Please include part of your CPP code where you feel the issue might be there.

Comment: @KunalPuri added the body of insert function. I feel like the problem is either insert or operator= function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost assuredly, your insert code looks like the following:

```
bool List::insert(const Patient& newElement)
{
    ...
    elements[someIndex] = newElement;
    ...
}
```

This is not putting the `newElement` into the array, it is assigning it to the existing item in the array (i.e., calling `Patient::operator=`).

Thus, they are two separate objects. Changing the one outside the array has no effect on the one in, and vice versa.

You might want something in `List` that can return a reference to one of the array objects to allow you to change it. E.g.,

```
Patient& List::operator[](size_t index)
{
   //<test here to make sure index is in range>
   return elements[index];
}
```

This would allow you to do something like:

```
Patient& pat = theList[0];
pat.setEmail("test@email.com");
```

and the item in the array would show that change.

---

And/or, I'm misreading, and you just haven't implemented `operator=` correctly.

Comment: What should I do so that changing the object outside the array also effects the object inside the array? Is this even possible with static arrays?

Comment: Possible, with pointers, but messy. I'd recommend not doing that, and just changing the item in the array; see my edit.

Comment: it works when `Patient& pat = theList[0];` but when there is an object called `an_obj` already inserted in the array and when I write `Patient& pat = an_obj;` and `pat.setEmail("test@email.com");` it does not change the value.

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek Include example of the code that you are using for this purpose in your question.

Comment: @DenizErenEvrendilek Maybe I got the issue that you are facing. I think you are doing this:

`Patient myobj("blah", "blah", "blah", "blah");
...
List theList;
theList.insert(myobj);
...
myobj.setEmail("blah2");`

And now, you are expecting the change to happen. If this is the case, then I think Phil M's answer's first paragraph elaborates that. Seems like you are from Java background. But C++ is quite different.

Comment: I think if you're still having issues, then you need to, as a few comments have suggested, create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, and edit your original question to include it.